# How to create a smooth width transition for digits in a rolling counter using `framer-motion`, `TypeScript`, `TailwindCSS`, and `React`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I've implemented a rolling counter using the  component, incorporating framer-motion, TypeScript, TailwindCSS, and React. However, I'm facing an issue with the smoothness of the animation when the width of a digit changes during the transition. Currently, the transition appears abrupt and "jumps" to the new width instead of smoothly adjusting.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
// RollingAnimatedNumbers.tsx

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
  const ref = useRef<T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};

export default usePrevious;;

function formatForDisplay(
  number: number,
  locale: string,
  decimals: number,
  showSeparator: boolean
): (string | number)[] {
  const options: Intl.NumberFormatOptions = {
    maximumFractionDigits: decimals,
    minimumFractionDigits: decimals,
  };
  options.useGrouping = showSeparator;

  return Math.max(number, 0)
    .toLocaleString(locale === 'en-BD' ? 'en-IN' : locale, options)
    .split("")
    .reverse();
};

function getLocaleDigits(locale: string) {
  const digits = [];
  for (let i = 9; i >= 0; i--) { digits.push(i.toLocaleString(locale)) };
  return digits;
};

function convertLocaleDigitToEnglishDigit(digit: string, locale: string): string {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    const localeDigit = i.toLocaleString(locale);
    if (localeDigit === digit) {
      return i.toString();
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`Invalid locale-specific digit: ${digit}`);
}

function SymbolColumn({ symbol }: { symbol: string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{symbol}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

function NumberColumn({
  digit,
  delta,
  locale,
}: {
  digit: string | number;
  delta: string | null;
  locale: string;
}) {
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState(0);
  const [animationClass, setAnimationClass] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const previousDigit = usePrevious<string | number | undefined>(digit);
  const columnRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const setDigit = (digit: string | number) => {
    if (columnRef.current) { 
      setYPosition(columnRef.current.clientHeight * parseInt(convertLocaleDigitToEnglishDigit(digit.toString(), locale), 10));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimationClass(previousDigit !== digit ? delta : "");

  }, [digit, delta, locale]);

  useEffect(() => setDigit(digit), [digit]);

  return (
    <div className="ticker-column-container" ref={columnRef}>
      <motion.div animate={{ y: yPosition }} className={`ticker-column ${animationClass}`} transition={{ type: 'keyframes', ease: 'easeIn' }}>
        {getLocaleDigits(locale).map((localeDigit, index) => (
          <div key={`locale-digit-${index}`} className="ticker-digit">
            <span>{localeDigit}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </motion.div>
      <span className="number-placeholder">{digit}</span>
    </div>
  );
};


type RollingNumberProps = {
  value: number;
  locale: string;
  decimals?: number;
  showSeperator?: boolean;
};

export default function RollingAnimatedNumbers({ value, locale, showSeperator, decimals }: RollingNumberProps) {
  
  const numArray = formatForDisplay(value, locale, decimals || 0, showSeperator || false);
  const previousNumber = usePrevious<number | undefined>(value);

  let delta: string | null = null;
  if (previousNumber && value > previousNumber) { delta = "increase" };
  if (previousNumber && value < previousNumber) { delta = "decrease" };

  return (
    <div className="ticker-view">
      {numArray.map((digit, index) => (
        digit === ',' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol="," /> :
        digit === '.' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol="." /> :
        digit === ' ' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol=" " /> :
        <NumberColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} digit={digit} delta={delta} locale={locale} />
      ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

I attempted to dynamically retrieve and adjust the width using `useRef()` and subsequently applying the changing width to the `<motion.div />` element. However, this approach did not yield the desired results. Here's the relevant code snippet for reference:

```
// RollingAnimatedNumbers.tsx

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
  const ref = useRef<T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};

export default usePrevious;;

function formatForDisplay(
  number: number,
  locale: string,
  decimals: number,
  showSeparator: boolean
): (string | number)[] {
  const options: Intl.NumberFormatOptions = {
    maximumFractionDigits: decimals,
    minimumFractionDigits: decimals,
  };
  options.useGrouping = showSeparator;

  return Math.max(number, 0)
    .toLocaleString(locale === 'en-BD' ? 'en-IN' : locale, options)
    .split("")
    .reverse();
};

function getLocaleDigits(locale: string) {
  const digits = [];
  for (let i = 9; i >= 0; i--) { digits.push(i.toLocaleString(locale)) };
  return digits;
};

function convertLocaleDigitToEnglishDigit(digit: string, locale: string): string {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    const localeDigit = i.toLocaleString(locale);
    if (localeDigit === digit) {
      return i.toString();
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`Invalid locale-specific digit: ${digit}`);
}

function SymbolColumn({ symbol }: { symbol: string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{symbol}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

function NumberColumn({
  digit,
  delta,
  locale,
}: {
  digit: string | number;
  delta: string | null;
  locale: string;
}) {
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [animationClass, setAnimationClass] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const previousDigit = usePrevious<string | number | undefined>(digit);
  const columnRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const placeholderRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);

  const setDigit = (digit: string | number) => {
    if (columnRef.current) { 
      setYPosition(columnRef.current.clientHeight * parseInt(convertLocaleDigitToEnglishDigit(digit.toString(), locale), 10));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimationClass(previousDigit !== digit ? delta : "");

    // Calculate the width of the widest digit
    if (placeholderRef.current) {
      setWidth(Math.max(...getLocaleDigits(locale).map(d => placeholderRef.current ? placeholderRef.current.offsetWidth : 0)));
    }

  }, [digit, delta, locale]);

  useEffect(() => setDigit(digit), [digit]);
  console.log(digit, width);


  return (
    <div className="ticker-column-container" ref={columnRef}>
      <motion.div animate={{ x: width, y: yPosition }} className={`ticker-column ${animationClass}`} transition={{ type: 'keyframes', ease: 'easeIn' }}>
        {getLocaleDigits(locale).map((localeDigit, index) => (
          <div key={`locale-digit-${index}`} className="ticker-digit">
            <span>{localeDigit}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </motion.div>
      <span ref={placeholderRef} className="number-placeholder">{digit}</span>
    </div>
  );
};


type RollingNumberProps = {
  value: number;
  locale: string;
  decimals?: number;
  showSeperator?: boolean;
};

export default function RollingAnimatedNumbers({ value, locale, showSeperator, decimals }: RollingNumberProps) {
  
  const numArray = formatForDisplay(value, locale, decimals || 0, showSeperator || false);
  const previousNumber = usePrevious<number | undefined>(value);

  let delta: string | null = null;
  if (previousNumber && value > previousNumber) { delta = "increase" };
  if (previousNumber && value < previousNumber) { delta = "decrease" };

  return (
    <div className="ticker-view">
      {numArray.map((digit, index) => (
        digit === ',' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol="," /> :
        digit === '.' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol="." /> :
        digit === ' ' ? <SymbolColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} symbol=" " /> :
        <NumberColumn key={`ticker-item-${index}`} digit={digit} delta={delta} locale={locale} />
      ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

```
/*  index.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .ticker-view {
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .number-placeholder {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .ticker-column-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .ticker-column {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1000%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .ticker-digit {
    width: auto;
    height: 10%;
  }
  
  .ticker-column.increase {
    animation: pulseGreen 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 1;
  }
  
  .ticker-column.decrease {
    animation: pulseRed 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 1;
  }
  
  @keyframes pulseGreen {
    0%,
    100% {
      @apply text-green-100;
    }
  
    50% {
      @apply text-green-500;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes pulseRed {
    0%,
    100% {
      @apply text-red-100;
    }
  
    50% {
      @apply text-red-500;
    }
  }

}
```

Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve a smoother animation for the width transition of digits in this rolling counter? Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated.